# How can I run Pygame (and python in general) in xcode?

Tags: python, xcode

I want to put a simple python game in the IOS app store but I am struggling to get it work properly in xcode, which prevents me from easily publishing the app.

I have looked online and I am able to open the python in xcode, I just can't get it to run. I am not sure it is possible, but I have seen some older forum that suggest it is.

I have tried to open and run the python code in xcode, and I assumed it would run similar to swiftUI which is more purpose built but it did not work as expected.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- make sure you have the latest versions of python (use brew) and xcode.
- find the location of your python install using `where python3`.
- run the commands:

```
cd location_of_python3
ln python3 examplePython3
```

- create an external build system

  - go to File->New->Project->Other->External Build System [image: external build system]
  - in the next prompt set the product name (doesn't matter what)
  - in the build tool section, set the path of the `where` command  [image: prompt]
  - now you can see your project's info screen [image: info screen]
- make a new python file

  - File->New->File->macOS->Empty-> click choose
  - choose a name for your python file (.py included) [image]
- scheme editing

  - click the target [image]
  - click `Edit Scheme`
  - click `Executable` -> `Other` (this will open a finder)
  - press CMD + SHIFT + G
  - enter the path from the `where` command [image]
  - click `Go`
  - search for the python3 linked file created in the third step
  - choose the home file
- add launch arguments

  - next to the info section, you can also see the `Arguments` section.
  - click that
  - In `Arguments Passed On Launch`, click the `+` button and give the python filename as input. [image]
  - press save
- set the working directory

  - next to the `Arguments` tab, you can see a `Options` tab.
  - click that
  - use a custom working directory
  - set the path as the project path
- debug the executable

  - go to the `Info` tab
  - uncheck the `Debug executable` option [image]
- test

  - open your python file via xcode
  - write some python code
  - click `Run` and see the output!

If you have any other questions, just ask.